# Statically linked program OK with gcc 4.7, fails with gcc 4.8. Uses dlopen at run time

Tags: linux, gcc, glibc, static-linking

I have a program resolving usernames to uids at run time using code like:

```
pw_user = getpwnam(username);
```

This specific call requires system's libc at runtime, even when the program is statically linked.

As I can't trust the run time environment, this program is statically linked and this call is ran inside a dedicated fork under user nobody.

When built on a Debian Wheezy box with GCC 4.7.2, this works just fine in any runtime environment. On the contrary, when build on an Ubuntu Trusty box with GCC with GCC 4.8.2 the build works fine but the user name resolve always fails.

This was built with:

```
gcc -Wall -W -Werror -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat \
    -Werror=format-security -static  main.c -o main
```

Most of the arguments here come from `dpkg-buildflags --get CFLAGS` which yields the same output under both environment.

I suspect there may be changes in GCC 4.8 affecting ldopen in statically linked binaries but I did not notic anything similar from GCC's Changelog (https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/changes.html).

Another possible suspect could be glibc. Version under wheezy is glibc-2.13-1 while version under Ubuntu is glibc-2.19-1.

Comment: Do you mean `dlopen()` rather than `ldopen()`?  Google search would prefer to show `dlopen()`, but there do seem to be `ldopen()` functions for some non-Linux platforms (HP-UX, AIX, SCO), and there does seem to be a GNU library that simulates it (and its relatives).

Comment: Hmm, thanks. Guess I typed too quickly

Answer (score 0):

> This specific call requires system's libc at runtime, even when the program is statically linked.

That is correct, but it's not the *whole* story. You should be getting a warning that the version of `libc.so` installed at runtime must be the *same* as what you used at link time.

In other words, by linking your binary statically you are making your binary extremely non-portable. It will *only* work on systems with `glibc-2.13` (or `glibc-2.19`) and *nowhere* else.

> When built on a Debian Wheezy box with GCC 4.7.2, this works just fine in any runtime environment.

If so, it's only by accident.

> when build on an Ubuntu Trusty box with GCC with GCC 4.8.2 the build works fine but the user name resolve always fails.

It should *not* fail on the same machine (i.e. one with `glibc-2.19`), and it may fail on any other machine. This is as designed.

> As I can't trust the run time environment, this program is statically linked and this call is ran inside a dedicated fork under user nobody.

You must also run this program in a chroot, with `libc.so` that matches your build environment. Nothing else is expected to work.